# NullPointException in FaceConverter

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans

Im developing using jpa and jsf.I'm not place all the code because is very large
I have an NullPointException in a code generated for netebeans 7.2. I think that netbeans is making the error, but i cant fix it.

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = MaterialEntrada.class)
public static class MaterialEntradaControllerConverter implements Converter {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        MaterialEntradaController controller = (MaterialEntradaController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "materialEntradaController");
        return controller.ejbFacade.find(getKey(value));
    }

    java.lang.Integer getKey(String value) {
        java.lang.Integer key;
        key = Integer.valueOf(value);
        return key;
    }

    String getStringKey(java.lang.Integer value) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(value);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (object instanceof MaterialEntrada) {
            MaterialEntrada o = (MaterialEntrada) object;
            return getStringKey(o.getId());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("object " + object + " is of type " + object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type: " + MaterialEntrada.class.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

The error is caused by the line :

```
return controller.ejbFacade.find(getKey(value));
```

ejbFacate is null, but controller is not null.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that controller is being initialized by jsf but ejbfacade is not.  Either add the code necessary to do this to the constructor or create a getter to do it at invocation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I don't want to break the structure of jsf.
Where and how put the code?
Sorry for my ignorance